# In groovy how to read xml and place that in JMS message

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jms

I try to send a message to the JMS like this it works

```
MessageProducer messageProducer =queueSession.createProducer( queueSend );
TextMessage textMessageSend = queueSession.createTextMessage();
textMessageSend.setText("ddjhdfsdfjskdhfshkfas")
messageProducer.send( textMessageSend );
```

but instead of placing my message in the textMessageSend.setText i want to read the message out of XML file how can you do that

Comment: what does the file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML looks like:

```
<messages>
  <message id="1">Hello</message>
  <message id="2">Goodbye</message>
  <message id="3">Whatever</message>
</messages>
```

Then you could write a function like:

```
def sendMessage( MessageProducer messageProducer, String id ) {
  String message = new XmlSlurper().parse( new File( 'MESSAGES.xml' ) )
                                   .message.find { it.@id == id }.text()
  if( message ) {
    queueSession.createTextMessage().with { tm ->
      tm.text = message
      messageProducer.send( tm )
    }
  }
}
```

So calling:

```
sendMessage( messageProducer, '1' )
```

would send the message `"Hello"`

Comment: Obviously, loading your xml file once using XmlSlurper and then querying this object would be faster than parsing the xml every time you send a message